# Point all subdomains of domain1 to the same subdomain of domain2 (masked)

Tags: web-hosting, dns, godaddy

I own two domains: `example.com` and `example.net`
My 'main' domain is example.com - it has several subdomains pointing to different resources. I want example.net to behave just like example.com, only that the user sees a different domain ending in his browser. So .example.com should be pointed to .example.net. Is this possible? (My provider is godaddy if that's important)

Comment: Is that really what you want? I wouldn't recommend having two domains that mirror each other because the duplication will hurt SEO and it will dilute your brand.  You usually want to redirect to the main one so that search engines know what to index and all users see your preferred brand name.

Comment: I agree that having a single URL (ie a canonical URL) is a best practice - although I am not convinced that this duplicate content will hurt SEO.   Regardless, one way this would be handled would be by having a single virtualhost with both domains pointed to it and the appropriate config to recognise all domains - and if you are using HTTPS, the certificate would need to include all domain variants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case somebody else is having the same question: No it's not possible to achieve this via DNS only. There are some ways to achive this using a proxy server, but for me that was not relevant